# Getting transport type from Google Analytics (analytics.js)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I can set a preference for one of the three transport mechanism (beacon, xhr or image) Google Analytics uses with something like:

```
ga('set', 'transport', 'beacon');
```

but the actual transport used for a request will depend on browser support and the size of the payload. Is there a way to read which mechanism GA actually chooses? Using model.get('transport') just gives me back my preference.